# Creating buttons for a popup(Speech Bubble) in Mapbox using Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapbox

I posted another question with the same code, but this question is different.

I want to add buttons in the bottom right corner of my Speech bubble that displays

```
Hello World! 
Welcome to my marker!
```

I want to know how to place the buttons there, but if you want to know what the buttons would do, one of them would keep track of how many upvotes the bubble got by other users, and the other would send a request to another user.

Also, I found [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/custom-callout/) that looks like it implements a different version of a speech bubble(popup) that may be better to use

```
import Mapbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // Set the map’s center coordinate and zoom level.
        mapView.setCenter(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7326808, longitude: -73.9843407), zoomLevel: 12, animated: false)
        view.addSubview(mapView)

        // Set the delegate property of our map view to `self` after instantiating it.
        mapView.delegate = self

        // Declare the marker `hello` and set its coordinates, title, and subtitle.
        let hello = MGLPointAnnotation()
        hello.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7326808, longitude: -73.9843407)
        hello.title = "Hello world!"
        hello.subtitle = "Welcome to my marker"

        // Add marker `hello` to the map.
        mapView.addAnnotation(hello)
    }

    // Use the default marker. See also: our view annotation or custom marker examples.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        return nil
    }

    // Allow callout view to appear when an annotation is tapped.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Below is what I would like my expected output to look like approximately

[image]

Comment: Are you want to customize your map annotation view or anything else? Can you please add a screenshot of your expected result.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I added what my expected output should look like. Theres an upvote button, a message button, and then a view profile button. I'm mostly just wondering how to get the buttons into the speech balloon and then how to make them access certain requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the built-in Mapbox callout you may want to consider implementing the [`-mapView:rightCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.4.1/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:rightCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation:)
 delegate method that allows you to further customize an MGLCallout as illustrated in this example: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/default-callout/. That delegate method returns a UIView so you can [customize the UIView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls) however you'd like to contain the buttons you want.

You'll notice in the example that another delegate method, [`-mapView:annotation:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.4.1/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:annotation:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:) is also implemented. This gets called when the right callout accessory view (returned by `-mapView:rightCalloutAccessoryViewForAnnotation:`) is selected, so you could adapt this by placing your logic in that delegate method when a user selects the right side of the callout view.

Comment: How would I put the buttons inside? Also I have another bounty where I'm wondering how to make the callout's appear when given input by the user (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574121/ios-creating-permanent-speech-balloons-for-annotations-using-mapbox) thank-you.

Comment: I don't understand how that example (https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/default-callout/.) is an example for customizing the mglCallout. I don't know which part is the customization. I see that it provides links to the definitions of MGLCalloutViewDelegate and MGLCalloutView, but doesn't provide any examples as far as I can see

Comment: So I'm still have quite a bit of trouble with this. If you have time, could you check out my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53689040/creating-a-custom-ui-view-class-to-use-as-a-map-annotation @nbsa